# How to return custom value immediately while debugging in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

As in topic, is any way to return custom value immediately while debugging in Android Studio?

I know I can change some values during execution time / debugging, can I set some custom return value for function? For example I have method:

```
1    public boolean isValid(){
2>        return foo.checkThis() || foo.andThis() || foo.atc();
3    }
```

If I am in debugging mode and my execution point is in line 2 may I return true/false by myself without checking these conditions? Just to speed up debugging and check some behaviors depends on return values.

Edit:
Yup I know I can do it like this:

```
public boolean isValid(){
    boolean someValueToSet = foo.checkThis() || foo.andThis() || foo.atc();
    return someValueToSet;
}
```

And during execution time I am able to change value when my execution point is on return statement.

But I wonder is any solution for first example.

Comment: if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){}

Comment: @SamirMangroliya yes but I have to change code. So I can hard code return statement with value true/false, it will be the same result. It could be better to store return value in variable and in next statement return this value. Than i will can change this value during runtime.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage